# Are excel formulas recalculated when sorting?

Tags: excel

I have tried googleing for an answer but could not find any answers so I try here.

The table below contains values in A and B columns, a formula formatted as text in the C column and the same formula formatted as a real formula (`=A1+B1` etc.) which displays the result in column D.

```
    A     B     C     D
1   1     1   A1+B1   2
2   2     2   A2+B2   4
3   3     3   A3+B3   6
```

If I then sort the table on A in descending order so it looks like below:

```
    A     B     C     D
1   3     3   A1+B1   6
2   2     2   A2+B2   4
3   1     1   A3+B3   2
```

**Are the formulas recalculated when sorting?** 
Dealing with small tables or sheets such as this it does not really matter - but if the file contains more than a couple of thousands rows and complex formulas recalculating should be kind of slow. **Is it a good idea to copy D and paste as values in D before sorting if I am finished editing the formula?**

Comment: Yes, it's a very good idea if you want to save time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculation does seem to be triggered when sorting.

You can as you state copy/paste values, but another way to get around this, is to enable manual calculation. You can do this at:

File --> Options --> Formulas --> Manual Calculation

This way you can choose by yourself when to calculate the formulas by pressing F9.
I would not leave this on indefinitely, since it can give a wrong view on the data, but when manipulating the data, this feature can come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if I use the [Volatile Formulae tool](http://www.decisionmodels.com/Downloads/VolatileFuncs.zip) from Charles Williams, Excel is recalulating the formulae on the sort

However - the tool also indicates the sort recalculates even when there are no formulae.